# Play video from a byte array

Tags: vb.net, arrays, video

I am using visual basic .NET and I want to play a video from a byte array that I have, but without saving it first at the disk. Directly from that array. I tried the directshow lib for a while but didn't managed to find a way to play it. WMP didn't worked either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is no stock component to stream from memory, however the task has more or less good generic solution. A number of files/formats are playable starting from so called [File Source (Async) Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375641.aspx), which is a generic file/data accessor. If you could provide a similar/compatible source filter which streams from memory, it would wokd great and cover a number of formats at a time.

Provided that you are going to have hard time doing it in VB.NET, and in managed code in general, you will perhaps need a third party solution for this. So you might eventually end up with a much easier workaround to save data into temporary file and play it from there.